# Mongo fails on read-only permissions for a directory owned by the executing user

Tags: mongodb, permissions, ubuntu-18.04, chmod

I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04 as regular sudo-er user:

```
test:~$ whoami
mugen
```

And have a `db` directory in my home (omitted irrelevant files):

```
test:~$ ls -la /home/mugen
total 64
drwxr-xr-x  7 mugen mugen 4096 Mar 17 14:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root  root  4096 Mar 17 13:32 ..
-rw-------  1 root  root  1778 Mar 17 14:07 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 mugen mugen  220 Apr  4  2018 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 mugen mugen 3771 Apr  4  2018 .bashrc
drwx------  2 mugen mugen 4096 Feb 25 08:20 .cache
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  4096 Mar 17 13:43 .config
drwxrwxr-x  4 mugen mugen 4096 Mar 17 14:09 db
```

I'm trying to run mongo using: `mongod --dbpath /home/mugen/db`

But it fails on the following:

```
2020-03-17T14:10:10.735+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-03-17T14:10:10.738+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=14315 port=27017 dbpath=/home/mugen/db 64-bit host=test
2020-03-17T14:10:10.738+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.3
2020-03-17T14:10:10.738+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4
2020-03-17T14:10:10.738+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
2020-03-17T14:10:10.738+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-03-17T14:10:10.738+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-03-17T14:10:10.738+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-03-17T14:10:10.738+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2020-03-17T14:10:10.738+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-03-17T14:10:10.738+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-03-17T14:10:10.738+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/home/mugen/db" } }
2020-03-17T14:10:10.739+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /home/mugen/db, terminating
2020-03-17T14:10:10.739+0000 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2020-03-17T14:10:10.739+0000 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2020-03-17T14:10:10.739+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-03-17T14:10:10.739+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

If I add "others" write permission to the directory, it works fine. But I don't want to. Doesn't `mongod` run as the executing user? Can I configure it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Troubleshooting - The data directory must be accessible](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/installation-ubuntu-community-troubleshooting/index.html#the-data-directory-must-be-accessible)

> The data directory must be configured with the appropriate permissions and ownership settings to allow the **mongod** to read, write, and navigate the directory contents (rwx user or group permissions).

You must permit user `mongod` to write to this folder. Or you could add user `mongod` to group `mugen` for example.

Comment: Can I configure `mongod` to run with a different user?

Comment: Perhaps you can set it in the service config file. Why do you want it to run as a different user?

Comment: Organization policy dictates directory permissions and ownership. would service config file also apply to running from command line and not as a service?

Comment: Of course not, settings in service file do not apply to comment line - typically running MongoDB from command line is only used for testing and/or maintenance but never for normal operation.